# Confused with this simple normalization function

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, normalization

Apparently this code below is supposed to normalize the columns in `x` values.

```
#normalize columns
def normalize_cols(m):
    col_max = m.max(axis=0)
    col_min = m.min(axis=0)
    return (m-col_min)/(col_max - col_min)

x_vals_train = np.nan_to_num(normalize_cols(x_vals_train))
x_vals_test = np.nan_to_num(normalize_cols(x_vals_test))
```

However, I am a bit confused.

Firstly, does the function normalize the data by column by column? If so, how and why? (Because we are inputting the whole columns at once.)

Secondly, documentation of [`np.nan_to_num`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nan_to_num.html) says that:

> Replace nan with zero and inf with large finite numbers.

But why is that used here? I don't get why we would have to replace zeros after we normalize the data?

Comment: First question: It utilises [numpy broadcasting](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/numpy/numpy_broadcasting.htm). `col_max` and `col_min` are arrays that are subtracted column-wise from the whole array. Second: If all values in a column are the same, the normalisation will return `nan`.

Comment: @MrT I see, about the second part, so the only purpose of writing that function is to prevent problems in cases where some columns have same values in every entry?

Comment: Or where the difference between min and max is extremely small, creating an overflow in the division, I suppose.